# Rails remote true form's controller not respoding with json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, forms, model-view-controller

In rails I've got a form with remote true in it like so:

```
<%= form_for(@thing, :html => { :'data-type' => 'json' },  :remote => true ) do |f| %>
```

And I'm picking up the ajax event in the javascript with this:

```
$('#new_thing').bind('ajax:complete', function(json, status, xhr){
        console.log("complete!");
        console.log(json);
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(status);
});
```

In the controller I have the line of code to respond to it like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @thing }
end
```

The problem is the console logged return response from the server isn't a json object, it's status object and the json response is a text string under the property "responseText" which has been escaped.

How do I get the server to respond with just a json object of the @thing?

Is there something wrong in any of the stages in this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `parseJSON(json['responseText'])` to get JSON object of servers response. I think you should manually bind Ajax call on form submit event, to get JSON object without conversions in `success` handler of `$.ajax()` function